# Code fails when run by button

Tags: vba

I have this procedure in a call sequence linked to a button. This does not always work when called by the button but always works when run separately. Any thoughts as to why?  The purpose of this procedure is to analyze numbered accounts and classify them.

```
 Sub IndexMatchBsIS()

        'declare the variable
        Dim lr As Long

        'create formula to calculate the last row based on number of materials in column J

        lr = Sheets("JDE TB").Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'declare a variant to store the row count
        Dim x As Variant

        'row that I want to start in
        x = 2

        'declare variables as ranges
        Dim rng As Range, Cell As Range

        'initialize the Range object rng with Range("E2:the last row in column E")
        Set rng = Sheets("JDE TB").Range("n2" & ":" & "n" & lr)


        'Add the For Each Next loop.
        For Each Cell In rng

        'Perform the index match calculation without using the spreadsheet filldown method

    If Cell(x, 3) > 50000 Then

    Cells(x, 14).Value = "IS"
    Else
    Cells(x, 14).Value = "BS"
    End If


        'Add the next row to the current count
        x = x + 1



            'loop to the next cell until complete
            Next Cell

        'exit the function

        Sheets("JDE TB").Range("k1").Value = "Entity"
        Sheets("JDE TB").Range("l1").Value = "ONESHIRE HFM Account"
        Sheets("JDE TB").Range("m1").Value = "ONESHIRE HFM Account Desc."
        Sheets("JDE TB").Range("n1").Value = "BS/IS"
        Sheets("JDE TB").Range("o1").Value = "Lv4 JDE"

    End Sub
```

Comment: "It's not working" is how your user might describe the problem. Isn't it infuriating to get an email like that, where you have no idea what the problem is? Well, that's exactly what your question does. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess and say that your if statement should look like this

```
  If Cell(x, 3) > 50000 Then
    Cell(x, 14).Value = "IS"
  Else
    Cell(x, 14).Value = "BS"
  End If
```

See how I made each one singular instead of plural? `Cells` refers to the active workbook, and your `Cell` variable is coming from your qualified range.

Answer (score 2):

Use Offset instead of the `x` variable.

```
If Cell.Offset(, 3) > 50000 Then    
    Cell.Offset(, 14).Value = "IS"
Else
    Cell.Offset(, 14).Value = "BS"
End If
```